# updating jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery graph which takes in data in sets for example

```
data: [
            [ vara,varb,varc,vard ],
```

I have an array of numbers such as

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to graph to take the first four numbers, then if theres any left over make a new data set. The end result graph data should represent

```
data: [
          [1,2,3,4],
          [5,6,7,8],
      ]
```

The whole point of doing so is that i wont have to manually enter data into the graph it would be read from the array.

Comment: The actual thing you are trying to do is not specific to jQuery. It is "how do I split an array into chunks in Javascript?" - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) and duplicates of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: The issue isn't splitting it into chunks, the issue is getting the chart to automatically fill in data.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "automatically fill in data"? If you pass it `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, what data do you expect will be automatically filled in?

Comment: The chart data takes in  variables as four at a time, i cannot pass in the whole array, it will not automatically carry over anything. Splitting up this is array is not an issue. I just need sets to be made without actually typing `[9,10,11,12]`

Comment: I need the chart, or a function to read the array, and generate its own data sets.

Comment: I can split  the initial array, but after that how will it get passed to the chart data sets?

Comment: What jQuery graph lib you are using? You need to make changes in that lib as per your requirement. Changes like the one answered below by Jeremy Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

You can build out your array 4 at a time like this:

```
var data = [[]];
var n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var counter = 0;
var dataIndex = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
    if(counter > 0 && counter % 4 == 0){
        dataIndex++;
        data[dataIndex] = [];
    }
    data[dataIndex].push(n[i]);
    counter++;
}
```

Opening the console and running it yields the results you expect.

Comment: how will i get the result to the chart?

Comment: The chart just needs the array to look like `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]` right?

Comment: Yes, so in order to get the information to the data set, all i would pass is `data[dataIndex], data[dataIndex]. The information needs to get sent to the chart data set, which is in another function.

Comment: So you could use the code I gave you and set `data: getDataSetFromArray([1,2,3,4....n])`, where getDataSetFromArray is a function that can return the values formatted how you need them.